# Retrieve Azure AD B2C UserPrincipaleName with MS Graph API

Tags: graph, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

On my Azure AD B2C tenant I have the following user.

It is created without a `name` and without a `mail`. Only `UserPrincipaleName` has a value set at creation time.

[image]

I try to collect that `UserPrincipaleName` using [microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

For some reason, the `UserPrincipaleName` I'm collecting doesn't have the same value and is rather made of the `object id` and the `domain name`.

```json
    {
        "businessPhones": [],
        "displayName": "unknown",
        "givenName": null,
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": null,
        "userPrincipalName": "12345678-abcd-efgh-12345678910a@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
        "id": "12345678-abcd-efgh-12345678910a"
    }
```

How can I retrieve the `my-user@gmail.com` value using msgraph API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that [identities object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0) had the information I was looking for :

```json
        "identities": [
            {
                "signInType": "emailAddress",
                "issuer": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
                "issuerAssignedId": "my-user@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
                "issuer": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
                "issuerAssignedId": "12345678-abcd-efgh-12345678910a@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        ]
```